# PHP(Laravel 5.4) Fatal error Allowed memory size ... > memory_limit not work

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error

I entered the command
`'php artisan key:generate'` or `'php artisan'`
but result is 'PHP Fatal error'

`$ php artisan
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to > allocate 20480 bytes) in laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php on line 128`

My PHP version is

PHP 7.2.11-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov  4 2018 05:10:57) ( NTS )

I tried to modify nginx and php.ini.

`vi /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
memory_limit = -1
OR
memory_limit = 1024MB`

and

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;` in nginx

`service nginx restart
 service php7.2-fpm restart`

But not work..

- I add to `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024MB');` in autoload_static.php
  but not work.

How can i do?

Please .. :)

Comment: The command you're using should never use that much memory. The problem lies somewhere else. With that said, it's close to impossible to know where exactly. I suggest you use a debugger and track down where the problem is.

Comment: When I run it local, it works fine.
It code to upload in git, and pull & run with server, but not working
There can not be a loop

Answer (score 4):

Now, I resolved it.

I edited only `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

But, need to edit with `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

`memory_limit = 2048MB`

It's run